# Why is doesn't TypeScript disallow reading an undefined variable inside a closure?

Tags: typescript

I just stumbled over this detail and couldn't find anything in the docs.
Here's some *valid* TypeScript code, which outputs `undefined`:

```
let x: number;
const f= () => {
    const y= x;
    console.log(y);
}
f();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwNwFgBQAxgPbwDOkAZgLwQAUAlBFQHwQDe+EXExZkAnjSi483HiVJFQAOmBEA5rX70RAX3wUGIoA)

TypeScript assumes (inside f) that x was assigned a value. y is of type `number`, not `number | undefined`. What's the reason for this?

I checked the docs about unsoundness, couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: This is going to turn out to be an instance of [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998); where control flow analysis does not cross function boundaries, which results in both false positives and false negatives, and there's nothing obvious to do about it.  I will look into it more when I get a chance.

Comment: Sorry about the typo in the question. It was late...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general issue here is highlighted in [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

The compiler performs what is known as [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to try to track what types variables can have at different places in the code.  It is this general feature which lets the compiler catch used-before-assigned errors:

```
let oops: string;
oops.toUpperCase(); // error, used before assigned

let okay: string;
okay = "assigned";
okay.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

This control flow analysis is useful, but far from perfect.  The compiler is not omniscient; it does not simulate every possible way a program can be run.  Nor does it have the reasoning capacity of a human developer.  Instead, it uses *heuristics*, a set of simplifying assumptions, to make type checking tractable during compilation.

Such limitations are easily observable when control flow crosses function boundaries.  It is not feasible for the compiler to actually follow the control flow into and out of a function, as if the function's body were [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).  Instead, it makes assumptions, which can lead to false positives (compiler errors for benign code) and false negatives (lack of compiler errors for buggy code).  This is the subject of microsoft/TypeScript#9998.

---

When this control-flow analysis functionality was being introduced, it turned out that the compiler would tend to warn that variables in the outer scope were not initialized.  This would have produced the error you are looking for.

Unfortunately, it would *also* warn in situations where the outer variable really *was* initialized, but the compiler didn't notice.  There were too many false positives, and a bug was filed: [microsoft/TypeScript#9757](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9757).

The fix was a simple change of assumption: as mentioned in [microsoft/Typescript#10815](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10815/commits/6e72858dbc885b334efe3f08dfdf0bac7bac782f), the compiler will "assume outer variables are always initialized in control flow analysis".

This eliminates one class of false positives, but introduces a class of false negatives, such as that in your code example.

---

It's possible that someone (you?) could [file a new issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new/choose) asking for this to be improved.  Perhaps one might suggest that in the case where the variable is *never* assigned in the whole code base, the compiler could revert to the behavior from before microsoft/TypeScript#10815.  That is, "assume an outer variable is assigned if and only if there is at least one assignment to that variable somewhere in the program".

But I wouldn't be optimistic about the chance of such a suggestion being adopted.  Every additional bit of analysis performed when checking variable initialization has a corresponding bit of performance cost.  Unless the extra work pays for itself in fixing problems with real-world TypeScript code, it won't be worth doing... even if it strictly improves the soundness and completeness of the type checker.

The question is therefore: how common is this problem?  I don't have a definitive answer for that, but I expect it's not very common... I have been unable to find an instance of someone reporting this exact situation.

In your case, the outer variable is never assigned.  I do see people reporting problems where the outer variable is used before assignment and the compiler does not catch it.  Even in this apparently more common case, it looks like they are not inclined to do anything about it: see [microsoft/TypeScript#42036](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42036).

Comment: Wow, what a great answer, thanks a lot. The issues you pointed at are very insightful too. And I learned about TDZ, which I wasn't aware of.